# For each unique value of some groupid column, how do I get rows with last 3 dates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table with columns: `FILING_ID`, `DATE`, and `BLAH`

I'm trying to write a query that for each `FILING_ID`, returns the rows with the *last three* dates. If table is:

```
   FILING_ID   DATE    
     aksjdfj   2/1/2006
           b   2/1/2006
           b   3/1/2006
           b   4/1/2006
           b   5/1/2006
```

I would like:

```
   FILING_ID   DATE    
     aksjdfj   2/1/2006
           b   3/1/2006
           b   4/1/2006
           b   5/1/2006
```

I was thinking of maybe running some query to figure out the 3rd highest date for each `FILING_ID` then doing a join and comparing the cutoff date with the `DATE`?

I use PostgreSQL. Is there some way to use limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT filing_id, date  -- more columns?
FROM  (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY filing_id ORDER BY date DESC NULLS LAST) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE  rn < 4
ORDER  BY filing_id, date;  -- optionally order rows
```

`NULLS LAST` is only relevant if `date` can actually be NULL.
If `date` is not unique, you may need to break ties to get stable results.

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

> Is there some way to use limit?

Maybe. If you have an additional table holding *all distinct* `filing_id` (and possibly a few more, which are removed by the join), you can use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` (`, LATERAL` is short syntax):

```
SELECT f.filing_id, t.*
FROM   filing f  -- table with distinct filing_id
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT date -- more columns?
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  filing_id = f.filing_id
   ORDER  BY date DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  3  -- now you can use LIMIT
   ) t
ORDER  BY f.filing_id, t.date;
```

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

If you don't have a `filing` table, you can create one. Or derive it on the fly:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: Thanks a ton! Tiny typo that rn isn't defined, but I think I figured that out on my own.

Comment: Thanks again! row_number(), partition, etc... slowly but surely I'm expanding my SQL toolkit!